# How can I make a change only in that element when I click on an element of the list view?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've seen similar questions and solutions on this topic, but haven't been able to find the exact answer I want. I'm trying to create an audio playlist. Every element in the list will have a play icon, when I click it, the sound will start playing, and the icon will turn into a pause icon. I'm trying to get audios from the api via [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) when I click it. My problem is that every item in this list has a play icon, and when I just click on one, all the others turn into pause icons.  Also, let's say an audio is playing from a list, when I try to play another one, I want the previous icon to revert to its original state. In the code I shared as an example, I removed the parts that I thought were irrelevant.

Code Sample:
'''

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

animationn = AnimationController(
vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
}


handlepress() {
setState(() {
audioplayerstate == PlayerState.PLAYING
? animationn.reverse()
: animationn.forward();
});
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
body: Center(
child: data != null
? StickyGroupedListView<dynamic, String>(
elements: data,
groupBy: (dynamic element) => element['type'],
groupSeparatorBuilder: (dynamic element) => Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
child: Text(element['type']),
),
indexedItemBuilder: (context, dynamic element, idx) =>
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
top: 4.0, left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 4),
child: ListTile(
minVerticalPadding: 30,
tileColor: Colors.white,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
title: Text(
element['name'],
),
trailing: 
IconButton(
iconSize: 50,
onPressed: () {
handlepress();
audioplayerstate == PlayerState.PLAYING
? pauseMusic()
: playMusic();
},
icon: AnimatedIcon(
icon: AnimatedIcons.play_pause,
progress: animationn,
color: Colors.blue.shade900,
),
color: Colors.blue.shade900)                     
),
), 
itemScrollController:
GroupedItemScrollController(), 
)
: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
));
}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that each element is using the same animation controller, so when that animation is triggered they all are animated at the same time. The best way to deal with this would be to make each tile it's own widget with it's own animation controller this way they can each be controlled separately, also I would add some sort of an identifier (maybe the name of the audio file) that indicates what is playing, and put that either into a ValueNotifer or make an implicitly animated widget.

Also Please indent your code that is nearly impossible to read and understand.

Comment: I actually tried similar to what you said, but I ran into the same problem. I guess I need to separate each one with its own key but also the pause icon of the previous one has to change to the play button when I click the play button on one. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you really don't need to mess with keys in this case, you just need some way of identifying which one is currently playing and make that be the only one that is animated forward, while all the others back. Again I would separate the build of each tile into its own widget, and also make that an ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget so that when the playing value changes things are animated correctly. Here is a link to the docs on implicitly animated widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ImplicitlyAnimatedWidget-class.html